# Test Class error

Tags: apex, unit-test, error

I have a test class, when i am excuting, getting the below error.

> System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id
>   a07J0000006hjjbIAA; 
>   first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION,
>   Only Finance, or SalesOps can affect a change of status of an asset .:
>   [Active__c]

I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Please try to select tags specifically related to the question, this helps to attract people with the right knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

This is a custom validation rule or trigger logic. You will need to adjust the rule or trigger appropriately to allow your validation to pass, or you will need to use System.runAs to run code as a Finance for SalesOps user; you will need to examine your system's configuration to determine which user to use.